# Creating a multi-region active-passive DR plan for Aurora MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, disaster-recovery, aws-aurora

I'm trying to create a disaster recovery plan for a cost efficient, maintainable and with little down for Aurora MySQL.

I want two read/write databases in two different regions, they can be separate databases called primary-us-east-1 and backup-us-east-2. I also want bidirectional replication between primary-us-east-1 to backup-us-east-2. Only one database will be connected to at all times so collisions are not a concern. In the event that region us-east-1 goes down, all I have to do is trigger a DNS switch to point to us-east-2 since backup-us-east-2 is already updated.

I've looked into Aurora Global Databases but this requires promoting a read replica in a secondary region to a master and then updating the DNS to recover from a region outage. I like the 0 work for data replication across several regions but I don't like losing the maintainability of the new resources in the process because the newly created resources (clusters/replicas) won't be maintainable in CDK if created through a lambda or by hand.

Is what I'm asking for possible? If yes, does anyone know of a replication solution so data can be copied primary-us-east-1 between backup-us-east-2?

Potential solution 1:

A potential solution is standing up the Aurora MySQL resources primary-us-east-1 and backup-us-east-2 using cdk. Keep them in sync using AWS Database Migration Service for continuous replication. Use a lambda to detect a region outage which will then perform the dns switch to point to backup-us-east-2. The only follow up task would be bringing primary-us-east-1 in sync with backup-us-east-2.

Comment: Does Aurora handle InnoDB Cluster or Galera?  If so, I suggest that either of those is a better DR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two Aurora (MySQL) **regional** clusters, one in each region.

Then setup bi-directional **binlog replication** between two Aurora regional clusters (with or without GTID).

Some steps are mentioned [here](https://minervadb.com/index.php/step-by-step-configuration-of-replication-between-aws-aurora-and-external-mysql-infrastructure/).